# Should a custom written binary tree have an interface too?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

There is an excellent article on MSDN about binary trees and how to create a custom binary tree [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms379572%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

**Question**

The code is below.It is a bit long but I am only pasting it for reference.(just a glance will tell you all).

My question actually is that if I do implement a custom binary tree like this below, should I first be defining an interface for each `Node, NodesList, BinaryTree, BinaryTreeNode` (4 classes)for later unit testing , or is it not needed in this case. I see that numerous collections in .net implement `IEnumerable`, should I do the same or is there any reason that I do not need to do that here?

```
public class Node<T>
{
        // Private member-variables
        private T data;
        private NodeList<T> neighbors = null;

        public Node() {}
        public Node(T data) : this(data, null) {}
        public Node(T data, NodeList<T> neighbors)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.neighbors = neighbors;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
            }
        }

        protected NodeList<T> Neighbors
        {
            get
            {
                return neighbors;
            }
            set
            {
                neighbors = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Node Class

```
public class NodeList<T> : Collection<Node<T>>
{
    public NodeList() : base() { }

    public NodeList(int initialSize)
    {
        // Add the specified number of items
        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++)
            base.Items.Add(default(Node<T>));
    }

    public Node<T> FindByValue(T value)
    {
        // search the list for the value
        foreach (Node<T> node in Items)
            if (node.Value.Equals(value))
                return node;

        // if we reached here, we didn't find a matching node
        return null;
    }
}
```

and finally

```
public class BinaryTreeNode<T> : Node<T>
{
    public BinaryTreeNode() : base() {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data) : base(data, null) {}
    public BinaryTreeNode(T data, BinaryTreeNode<T> left, BinaryTreeNode<T> right)
    {
        base.Value = data;
        NodeList<T> children = new NodeList<T>(2);
        children[0] = left;
        children[1] = right;

        base.Neighbors = children;
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Left
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                return null;
            else
                return (BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[0];
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>(2);

            base.Neighbors[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> Right
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                return null;
            else
                return (BinaryTreeNode<T>) base.Neighbors[1];
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.Neighbors == null)
                base.Neighbors = new NodeList<T>(2);

            base.Neighbors[1] = value;
        }
    }
}


public class BinaryTree<T>
{
   private BinaryTreeNode<T> root;

   public BinaryTree()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   public virtual void Clear()
   {
      root = null;
   }

   public BinaryTreeNode<T> Root
   {
      get
      {
         return root;
      }
      set
      {
         root = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you ever going to make three unrelated implementations of that interface? That is, the testing interface. Yes, do implement innumerable.

Comment: @EricLippert I don't know yet actually. That's why I wasn't sure if I might or not.  I just figured " well, it is like a collection, all collections in .net have interfaces implemented, so I should do the same". But as Alexai said , it will make applying Linq easy, I think I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, too long for comment:

It is always good idea to expose collection as `IEnumerable` since you can easily apply LINQ queries in such case.

Binary tree by itself is pretty useless and internal details (nodes) are even less interesting. So exposing inner details as interfaces likely will not be useful. Exposing binary tree as specific interface may be overkill too - if you need it to represent some sorted structure `IList`/`ICollection` or maybe `IDictionary` maybe enough.

Note that if you are building binary tree as base for several other interesting collections you may consider interfaces, but it should be driven by need to test particular pieces of code.

Comment: @Alexai Levenkov. Your LINQ queries reason is solid enough for it on its own, because I don't know if I will be building it as a base for other collections .